# How to pass runtime class to AfxBeginThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, object

```
Class A
{
    method1()
    {
         m_GetDataThread         = AfxBeginThread(B::method2, RUNTIME_CLASS, THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL, 1 << 20, STACK_SIZE_PARAM_IS_A_RESERVATION);
    }

}

Class B
{
    method2()
    {
         ----------
    }
}
```

Here if RUNTIME_CLASS was Class A, I can just pass this in place of RUNTIME_CLASS but how do I pass Class B in above case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `AfxBeginThread` has two overloads, one takes function or static method, another takes runtime class, they are mutually exclusive. And none takes non-static method (and such function that would take it without `this` could hardly exist)
2. `RUTNIME_CLASS` macro takes class name as a parameter, so the problem you are asking of is not a problem.
3. It is understood if you have to use MFC in 2020, but it is not understood anyway why do you have to use MFC threading facilities for new code in 2020. Consider `std::thread`, `std::async`, or at very least direct `_beginthreeadex`/`CreateThread`

Comment: When I pass class name as a parameter it gives error `no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list`

Comment: MFC custom RTTI has some implications. classes that are used with `RUNTIME_CLASS` must single-inherit from `CObject`, and have at least `DECLARE_DYNAMIC`, (or a superior `DECLARE_DYNCREATE`/`DECLARE_SERIAL`).

Comment: and to be used with `AfxBeginThread`, class must inherit from `CWinThread`